# Ошибка в плагине jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Если проскролить карусель полностью (кликая по правой ссылке(стрелке), а потом вызвать метод):

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', номер слайда);
```

то скролинг происходит не на тот слайд, который указан.
Заметил, что иногда меняется порядок li в ul карусели.
Кто знает в чем причина?

Comment: Без [минимального, полного, воспроизводимого примера](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Это происходит в чистом плагине, не на реальном сайте.
Просто беру example responsive jcarusel и происходит такой баг.
Это ошибка разработчика?

Comment: Если вы можете, например, в http://jsfiddle.net полностью воссоздать и продемонстрировать проблему с этим примером из документации (или откуда он взят), то вполне может быть. Только вот для того, чтобы сказать вам в чем именно ошибка, нужно  видеть этот самый пример, воссоздающий проблему.